# How to insert comma as value separator in a pandas data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my data frame I'm having a multi value column `value`

```
0      [0.66675711 0.20713726]
1                 [1.00000978]
2      [0.75725347 0.15414298]
3      [0.80648571 0.15190959]
4                 [1.00001001]
                ...
497    [0.76083511 0.1651703 ]
498               [1.00001001]
499               [0.84645146]
500    [0.74801773 0.18731603]
501               [0.99931085]
Name: value, Length: 502, dtype: object
```

I would like to put a comma `,` as separator between values as follows

```
0      [0.66675711,0.20713726]
1                 [1.00000978]
2      [0.75725347,0.15414298]
3      [0.80648571,0.15190959]
4                 [1.00001001]
                ...
497    [0.76083511,0.1651703 ]
498               [1.00001001]
499               [0.84645146]
500    [0.74801773,0.18731603]
501               [0.99931085]
Name: value, Length: 502, dtype: object
```

How to deal with this?

Regards,

Comment: How were the lists created because that is not a valid list if those two floats in indeed floats? Are they strings or is the whole list a string? What does `df['value'].values` return? or `df['value'][0]`

Comment: @It_is_Chris df['value'][0] it returns [0.66675711 0.20713726] , df['value'].values it returns the entire array i.e ['[0.66675711 0.20713726]' '[1.00000978]' '[0.75725347 0.15414298]'..]

Comment: in index 497, there's a space at the end. Is that by accident or there are cases like that?

Comment: @Pelide so you do not actually have list items in your dataframe, they are strings. So you can do something like `df['value'].str.replace(' ', ', ').apply(ast.literal_eval)`